# Where are Android Studio user options saved?

Tags: android, android-studio

I just upgraded to 0.8.1 (new beta version) and all my preferences were lost.  I have the old installation folder backed up but don't see any preference files, nor do I see any in %APPDATA%.  Any idea where they are?  I don't want to have to redo everything, especially formatter settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at `~/.AndroidStudioPreview`.

For the new Beta version, it is `~/.AndroidStudioBeta`.